# How to make the game restart (python turtle snake game)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I want to make the game restart after the player bumps a wall or itself(loses a game) I tried using tkinter but didn't know what to do with it now I'm just confused.
I also wanted to ask is there a way to ask the player how if he wants to play again after he loses or some feature like that.
And can I use buttons with turtle ?

Comment: What are you exactly talking about? Which game? Please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section. Then ask *one* question at a time and illustrate it with your coding efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import turtle

while True:
    # Your game code
    again = input("Do you want to play again? ")
    if again == 'yes':
        screen.clear()
    else:
        print('Bye!')
        break
    # If the player enters `yes`, the screen will be cleared, then the program will loop back to the top of this while loop
```

Comment: Sorry  I pasted what was on my clipboard, I didn't mean to say that. +1